# Very slow query when matching text field is not empty string

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a very simple query that is essentially this:

```
Select * from my_table Where my_field != '';
```

There are about 40,000 rows in the table and the "my_field" column is a text field (varchar 255)

The query takes about 39,000ms to run. I'm guessing because it's having to look through each record for things that are not empty strings. I've indexed the my_field column but it hasn't changed anything.

Just in case it's any use, here is the query plan:

```
"Seq Scan on my_table  (cost=0.00..3468.91 rows=39744 width=459)"
"  Filter: ((my_field)::text <> ''::text)"
```

What's my best option here?

Explain Analyze:

```
"Seq Scan on my_table  (cost=0.00..3468.91 rows=39730 width=459) (actual time=0.021..13.763 rows=39714 loops=1)"
"  Filter: ((my_field)::text <> ''::text)"
"Total runtime: 14.856 ms"
```

I added these indexes

```
CREATE INDEX aa_idx ON my_table(my_field);
CREATE INDEX aa_idx ON my_table(my_field) WHERE my_field <> '';
```

It's Postgres 9.1

**Edit: [2013-02-26 00:04GMT]**

Would there be any benefit to creating a partition on the "my_field" as the check constraint?

something like CHECK(my_field = '') and on partition 2 CHECK(my_field != '')

I'm guessing then all I'll have is a table with a lot of rows in it? But would this mean the select != '' query would then perform much faster even if the partition would contain about 80% of the data?

I also looked into full text searching, but that seemed a OTT for this. I also looked at making the column an int of 0 or 1 (bool) but this had no effect on performance (I guess because = 1 still brings back a lot of rows?)

Comment: 1) What is the probability for a record having a (non-) empty my_field: how many records satisfy the condition? 2) do you have statistics (did you run `vacuum analyze` after adding the index) ?

Comment: 1) more often than not, i'd say about 75% of the fields match the query.. 2) yes I ran a vacuum full analyze after. I also tried to add a partial index of where my_field <> '' but that didn't make any difference.

Comment: Best to show the `explain analyze` not just plain `explain`. Also: PostgreSQL version? What locale is your database in? And please show the definition of the index you added.

Comment: If 75% of the records match the query, a full table scan would be appropiate. With an estimation of 18 rows/page it would be hard to find a page *without* any wanted rows on it.

Comment: So what are my options? As the query takes an age to run (it's part of a larger deletion procedure) I'm basically finding all fields to delete.

Comment: options are: 1) run the query a second time (if the second query is not faster, your effective_cache_size is set too low)  2) replace the `select *` by `select COUNT(*)` (outputting the bulky results cots time and bandwidth, too)

Comment: my effective_cache_size is 512MB. What's a good size for this setting?

Comment: A good setting is `total_memory - xxx`, with xxx being the memory needed for OS and active running processes.

Comment: So if the server has 64GB Ram, i should be good to set it to at least 48GB?

Answer (score 2):

An index won't help you.  I think you need to find a better way to consolidate your deletion.

You say it is taking 39 sec to run but the actual query plan you provided is taking 15 ms to run, which is approx a factor of 2000 off.  I am having trouble imagining a case where caching would help that much unless we are talking about very wide tables with lots of TOASTed values.  This tells me that the actual problem is not in your select but rather elsewhere in your pipeline.  This could include round trip costs, and however you are doing the delete.

My recommendation is to look at statement consolidation.  This would mean avoid round trips and push as much logic into single queries as you can.  Since you haven't posted full context, I would suggest you might want to look into writeable CTE's for batching inserts, updates, and deletes together without round trips.